# How to find repeated sub string in a main string using VBScript

Tags: string, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

How to find repeated sub string in a main string using VBScript?

For example, if the string is

```
str = "Google mail, Google Maps, Google drive, Google music, Google play, Google office"
```

I need the the substring which is repeated in above string. Also its count.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why people are down voting this. Is this not a valid question or should I assume that people who down voted don't know the answer.

Better if u add a reason as comment for down voting.

Comment: Look into a `do ... loop` with `Instr`

Comment: `Instr(str,"Google")`
this is what you say, but i don't want to pass 'google' explicitly..It should automatically find the repeated word.

Comment: I presume people are downvoting, because your question is basically asking "please write code for me", which is not appreciated here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give the count of all words in a given substring.

```
 str = "Google mail, Google Maps, Google drive, Google music, Google play, Google office"

    Function RemoveDuplicates(str)
      If Trim(str) = "" Then
        RemoveDuplicates = Array()
        Exit Function
      End If

      Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
      d.CompareMode = vbTextCompare  'make dictionary case-insensitive

      For Each elem In Split(str)
        d(elem) = True
      Next

      RemoveDuplicates = d.Keys
    End Function

    sUniques = RemoveDuplicates(str)

    For k = 0 To UBound(sUniques)
            iCount = len(str) - len(replace(str, sUniques(k), ""))
            msgbox "The string " & sUniques(k) & " appeared " & iCount/len(sUniques(k)) & " times"
    Next
```

Using First function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20310733/2571523

Comment: Thanks Ankur jain. This worked for me perfectly.

Idid not expect answer from you. Iam the follower of your UFT blog...

Answer (score 1):

Finding word repetitions in 4 simple steps:

1. Remove interpunction from the string and mangle consecutive spaces to a single one, e.g. with a [regular expression replacement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300.aspx).

   ```
   Set re = New RegExp
   re.Pattern = " *[.,;!?'""_-] +| +"
   re.Global  = True
   str = re.Replace(str, " ")
   ```
2. [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5.aspx) the string at spaces.
3. Put each word as a key into a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4.aspx). Increment the value for the key if the word already [exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57hdf10z.aspx).
4. [Iterate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tywtbxd0.aspx) over the [keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/etzd1tzc.aspx) of the dictionary and output the key and value with the highest value.

   ```
   For Each word In dict.Keys
     If IsEmpty(mfu) Then
       mfu = word
     ElseIf dict(word) > dict(mfu) Then
       mfu = word
     End If
   Next

   WScript.Echo mfu & ": " & dict(mfu)
   ```

Comment: Most succinct answer, nicely considered.

Answer (score 1):

```
    str = "Google mail, Google Maps, Google drive, Google music, Google play, Google office"
    str1 = Split(replace(str,",","")," ")
    Set dic1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    On Error Resume next
    For Each a in str1
        dic1.Add a,"1"
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            dic1(a) = cstr(cint(dic1(a)) + 1)
            err.clear
        End If
    Next
    On Error Goto 0
    repeatedwords = ""
    For each keys in dic1
        If cint(dic1(keys)) > 1 Then
            repeatedwords = repeatedwords & vbNewline & vbNewline & keys & " repeated " & dic1(keys) & " times"
        End If
    Next
    msgbox repeatedwords
    Set dic1 = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeDup
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        On Error Resume Next
        Line=Inp.readline
        Dict.Add Line, ""
        If Err.Number <> 0 then
            If LCase(Arg(1)) = "l" then
                Dict.Remove Line
                Dict.Add Line, ""
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    For Each thing in Dict.Keys()
        Outp.writeline thing
    Next
End Sub
```

This uses a scripting dictionary to dedup lines. You can get an array of words by using the `Split()`. Add each one to a dictionary, if it errors it's a dup.

Answer (score 0):

To find occurances :

```
baseString = "Google mail, Google Maps, Google drive, Google music, Google play, Google office"
subString = "Google"
MsgBox "The "& chr(34) & subString & chr(34) & " appeared " &_
findOccurancesCount(baseString, subString) & " times !" & vbCrLF &_
"in " & vbCrLF & chr(34) & baseString & chr(34)_
,vbInformation,"FindOccurancesCount"
'*********************************************************************************
Function findOccurancesCount(baseString, subString)
    occurancesCount = 0
    i = 1
    Do
        foundPosition = InStr(i, Lcase(baseString), Lcase(subString))
        If foundPosition > 0 Then
            occurancesCount = occurancesCount + 1
            i = foundPosition + 1
        End If
    Loop While foundPosition <> 0
    findOccurancesCount = occurancesCount
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
```